# transform file/directory structure into 'tree' in vue json

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, tree

transform file/directory structure into 'tree' in vue json

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Officer",
        "isDirectory": true,
        "path": "Officer/EventReport/SelfReport/110-04-02/DADF.pdf"
    },
    {
        "name": "Officer",
        "isDirectory": true,
        "path": "Officer/EventReport/SelfReport/110-04-10/110010.pdf"
    },
    {
        "name": "Officer",
        "isDirectory": true,
        "path": "Officer/S_Meeting/W_Meeting/110-5/Officer_from.docx"
    },
    {
        "name": "Officer",
        "isDirectory": true,
        "path": "Officer/S_Meeting/W_Meeting/110-5/1620021359034.jpg"
    },
    {
        "name": "Officer",
        "isDirectory": true,
        "path": "Officer/S_Meeting/W_Meeting/110-5/2021-05-18_092810.png"
    }
]
```

There could be any number of arbitrary path's, this is the result of iterating through files and folders within a directory.

What I'm trying to do is determine the 'root' node of these. Ultimately, this will be stored in mongodb and use materialized path to determine it's relationships.

I hope I can show this one.

```
[
    {
        "name": "Officer",   //part1
        "isDirectory": true,
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "EventReport",  //part2
                "isDirectory": true,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "name": "SelfReport",  //part3
                        "isDirectory": true,
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "name": "2020-110-04-02",  //part4
                                "isDirectory": true,
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "RCBS.pdf",  // name
                                        "isDirectory": false
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "2020-110-04-10",  //part4 
                                "isDirectory": true,
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "1100_b.pdf",  //name
                                        "isDirectory": false
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "SecurityMeeting",  // part2
                "isDirectory": true,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "name": "SecurityWorkMeeting",  //part3
                        "isDirectory": true,
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "name": "2021-05-SecurityWorkMeeting",  //part4
                                "isDirectory": true,
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "Officer_Report.docx",  //name
                                        "isDirectory": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "16200.jpg",  //name
                                        "isDirectory": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "2021-05-18_2342.png",  //name
                                        "isDirectory": false
                                    }
                                ]
                            },      
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },    
]
```

method

```
let arr = xhr.data.UploadFile;
let tree = {};

arr.forEach(item => {
  let tokens = item.path.replace(/^\/|\/$/g, "").split("/");
  let current = tree;
  for (let i=0; i<tokens.length; i++) {
    if (!current[tokens[i]]) {
      current[tokens[i]] = {};
    }
    current = current[tokens[i]];
  }
});
const parseNode = function(node) {
  return Object.keys(node).map(key => {
    if (Object.keys(node[key]).length === 0) {
      return {
        isDirectory: false,
        name: key,
      };
    }
    return {
      isDirectory: true,
      name: key,
      items: parseNode(node[key]),
    };
  });
};
let result = parseNode(tree);
console.log("RESULT", result);
```

update [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVCYT.png)

I dont know why it will pass the parseNode = function(node), and cannot get result. And the items should be use array. Like this one

```
[
    {
        "name": "Officer",   //part1
        "isDirectory": true,
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "EventReport",  //part2
                "isDirectory": true,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "name": "SelfReport",  //part3
                        "isDirectory": true,
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "name": "2020-110-04-02",  //part4
                                "isDirectory": true,
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "RCBS.pdf",  // name
                                        "isDirectory": false
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "2020-110-04-10",  //part4 
                                "isDirectory": true,
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "1100_b.pdf",  //name
                                        "isDirectory": false
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "SecurityMeeting",  // part2
                "isDirectory": true,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "name": "SecurityWorkMeeting",  //part3
                        "isDirectory": true,
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "name": "2021-05-SecurityWorkMeeting",  //part4
                                "isDirectory": true,
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "Officer_Report.docx",  //name
                                        "isDirectory": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "16200.jpg",  //name
                                        "isDirectory": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "2021-05-18_2342.png",  //name
                                        "isDirectory": false
                                    }
                                ]
                            },      
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },    
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

Here is the full implementation, based upon my initial answer. I changed the forEach() into map() as it is more suitable in this case.

```
let arr = xhr.data.UploadFile;
let tree = {};

arr.forEach(item => {
  let tokens = item.path.replace(/^\/|\/$/g, "").split("/");
  let current = tree;
  for (let i=0; i<tokens.length; i++) {
    if (!current[tokens[i]]) {
      current[tokens[i]] = {};
    }
    current = current[tokens[i]];
  }
});
const parseNode = function(node) {
  return Object.keys(node).map(key => {
    if (Object.keys(node[key]).length === 0) {
      return {
        isDirectory: false,
        name: key,
      };
    }
    return {
      isDirectory: true,
      name: key,
      items: parseNode(node[key]),
    };
  });
};
let result = parseNode(tree);
console.log("RESULT", result);
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

You could build a map by iterating on the array (I named it data):

```
let tree = {};
data.forEach(item => {
  let tokens = item.path.split("/");
  let current = tree;
  for (let i=0; i<tokens.length; i++) {
    if (!current[tokens[i]]) {
      current[tokens[i]] = {};
    }
    current = current[tokens[i]];
  }
});
```

Then, walk through your map to build your result array:

```
const parseNode = function(node) {
  let res = [];
  Object.keys(node).forEach(key => {
    if (Object.keys(node[key]).length === 0) {
      res.push({
        isDirectory: false,
        name: key,
      });
    } else {
      res.push({
        isDirectory: true,
        name: key,
        items: parseNode(node[key]),
      });
    }
  });
  return res;
};
let result = parseNode(tree);
```

Comment: I had updated my content, could you help me check? I don't know why has null values

Comment: Hi, just use the whole code I provided you with, this will build the tree you want.

Comment: I had updated my context, could you help me check? I don't know why cannot show isDirectory, items

Comment: I had updated the answes, and I don't know why it is not run const parseNode = function(node) { ?

Comment: I would need more context to help you. To debug, you can try to assign directly your array, like that: `let arr = [ { "name": "Officer", "isDirectory": true, "path": "Officer/EventReport/SelfReport/110-04-02/DADF.pdf" }, /*remaining data...*/ ];` This is what I did for testing and it works properly.

Comment: thx bro, it's my mistake because I got wrong line to debugger. But, now is all down. :)

Comment: Do you have use this plugin before? 
https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxFileManager/
how could got the path when I create the new directory & path?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: do you know how should get click the current items values in the file manager?

Comment: Hi bro, how could add new filed name into the code? because I fotgot put fid field. So could I add it? like this isDirectory: false, name: key, fid : "11233",